# Hella bistable latching relay

Tags: latching-relay

I would like to understand how to connect the Hella Bistable Latching Relay https://www.delcity.net/store/Latching-Relays/p_818110.h_818111 The intended use is on a motorcycle to turn on and off an accessory by tapping a button which momentarily connects to ground. Each tap would sequentially turn on or turn off the accessory. [image: relay diagram and con]

Answer (score 1):

You would need 2 separate push-button switches for 'On' & 'Off'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

judging from the diagram That relay uses terminal 6 for positive and you ground terminal 1 or 2 to turn it on or off.

so to get it to do what you want would require an alternate acting push-button.

it's probably easier to use a latching push-button with an ordinary relay.

Or use a bunch of ordinary relays to build an alternate acting bistable

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want with a single push-to-make button.

A bi-stable latching relay would be a simple solution but I don't think they're available in automotive versions.

[image]

*Figure 1. Go to [HomoFaciens](http://www.homofaciens.de/technics-base-circuits-relay_en.htm) and click "Start animation" to see how the pawl mechanism is advanced on every impulse of the relay coil.*

No flip-flops, electronics or magic is required. Wire your button between the power-supply and the coil. Each impulse will change the state of the contact.

Imgur doesn't seem to like animated gifs.

---

To use your relay some electronics would be required and you probably want it to reset to the default position on power-up. All things considered I suspect that a latching push-button and a regular relay would be a simpler solution but it won't have the power-on reset.